# Ignoring missing/NA values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to construct a ggplot with some calculations but many of the rows has NA values (actually more complex than that, they do not register as NA values in R, they are actually character values labeled as n.a. (not recognised as N.A. values by R during import))

I am trying to carry out the followig ggplot, its a basic growth formula over time t: `(t - t-1) / t` How can I omit NA or character values. na.omit does not seem to work.

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = ((EBITDA.EUR.Last.avail..yr - EBITDA.EUR.Year...1) / EBITDA.EUR.Year...1)),
              y = ((Fixed.assets.EUR.Last.avail..yr - Fixed.assets.EUR.Year...1) / Fixed.assets.EUR.Year...1)),
              color = "red")) + 
      geom_point()
```

Comment: Please provide `dput(x)` so we can address the underlying data structure issue.

Answer (score 3):

Consider making your calculations prior to the ggplot call. In this case, you could save the calculations as a new data.frame (e.g. call it x) and apply the function `new_x = !is.na (x)` after assigning `NA` via `x[x=='n.a',]<-NA`. Use `new_x` in the ggplot call. IF the issue is indeed na values, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, `ggplot2` package ignores NA values. If your data contains NAs as character, you can try something like this before you make the plot:

```
x[x == "n.a."] <- NA
```

This, considering that `x` is your data.frame or vector, should convert all your character "NA" to authentic NA values that will be omitted by the `ggplot()` function.